# HoloLens2: I want to draw a target on the surface mesh where the user is looking

Tags: hololens, mrtk

On the HoloLens 2, I want to draw a target on the surface mesh where the user is looking. How do I get the vector pointer that represents the eye ray? I believe the cursor already finds out where this ray pointer collides with the surface mesh, however, it never uses the eye ray. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the HoloLens 1 and the HoloToolKit I used this - Worldposition:

```
Vector3 hitPosition = GazeManager.Instance.HitPosition;
```

For LocalPosition:

```
Vector3 hitPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(GazeManager.Instance.HitPosition);
```

Is in the new MRTK V2 something like the Gazemanager?
On the camera should be a script including the raycast...

Edit: Wait are u looking for the coordinates of your eye (cause I read that the HoloLens 2 includes eye-tracking)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MRTK v2, you'll want to look at calling `MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem.GazeProvider` or `MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem.EyeGazeProvider` from your code. If you're specifically looking for eye gaze, you'll want to check for the [`IsEyeGazeValid` property](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityEyeGazeProvider.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_Input_IMixedRealityEyeGazeProvider_IsEyeGazeValid) before asking for the gaze data. You'll also want to make sure you've checked Prefer Eye Gaze on your GazeProvider, and turned on eye gaze simulation in the input simulation profile, if needed for the editor.

[Prefer Eye Gaze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBczO.png)

Otherwise, if you want head gaze, the [HitPosition](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityGazeProvider.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_Input_IMixedRealityGazeProvider_HitPosition) and related properties should provide the information you need.

Additional information about eye tracking in MRTK v2 can be found in the [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/EyeTracking/EyeTracking_BasicSetup.html).

Answer (score 0):

[The eye tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.spatial.spatialpointerpose.eyes) is accessed as the following

1. add 'gazeInput' as Capability into your appx manifest
2. Before calling any Eye tracking API ask user for approval by calling [`EyesPose.RequestAccessAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.people.eyespose.requestaccessasync)
3. Take gaze ray

```cs
if(Windows.Perception.People.EyesPose.IsSupported)
{
    var gaze = Windows.UI.Input.Spatial.SpatialPointerPose.TryGetAtTimestamp(coordinateSystem, DateTime.Now).Eyes.Gaze;
    if(gaze != null)
    {
        var dir = gaze.Direction;
        var org = gaze.Origin;
    }
}
```